# json flag is out putting malformed json

Tags: webpack

I am running a npm script/command to produce a webpack stat file. The cli command is the following:

```
webpack --profile --json > stats.json
```

However this is producing a malformed json file. There are two timestamps at the beginning of the file that is breaking the analyzer tool I am trying to run against it. The top of the json starts like this:

```
[9:00:38 AM] Compiling webpack
[9:00:38 AM] Compiled webpack in 15s
{
 "errors": []
 "warnings": [
  ]
 ...
}
```

Those two timestamps are breaking the json file. Is there a way to not have those timestamps get injected into my stats file?

Comment: What's the reasoning for the down vote? I feel as if this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the issue. Those timestamps were not breaking the analyzer at all. The issue was actually inside my webpack.config.js file. There was an undefined variable being used and that somehow broke the analyzer. The error message the analyzer reported was misleading and reported the wrong line in the stat file for some reason.

So tl;dr version.

If you are running into this issue, double check your build process and make sure there are no errors, console.log, etc.. in your webpack.config.js file.

Also, to whomever down voted this. Come on? You have to give a good reasoning in the comments. How are people supposed to learn if you are just going to downvote and not leave any input?